# How do I get information out of a lambda expression in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda

I understand why lambda expressions can't mutate local variables, and I understand that they can access and mututae class fields. For me, lambdas create much more expressive code in many situations and I would like to use them more often.

My question is what the the best practices(s) for using lambda not as single-method object replacements, but to instead simplify code such as this:

```
int pairsFound = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counters.entrySet())
    {
        if (entry.getValue() == 2)
            pairsFound++;
    }
```

to

```
pairsFound = map.forEach((key, value) ->
{
    int z = 0;
    if (value == 2)
        z++;
    return z;
});
```

or

```
map.forEach((key, value) ->
{
    if (value == 2)
        pairsFound++;
});
```

One solution is to make `parisFound` an instance field. But instatizing variables that are never used outside of a single method seems like a code smell to me. Also, this won't work if the enclosing class is static (such as in a test run).

Are there other ways of getting information out of a lambda in a way that isn't any less safe than using a for each loop? I understand that there can be concurrency issues with lambdas, but in most of my simplifying use cases I don't know if the lambda would be any less safe than what it is replacing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way for this scenario is to create a stream, filter on the condition of `entry.getValue() == 2`, and then `count()` the result. Something like this:

```
long pairsFound = map.values().stream().filter(v -> v == 2).count(); //using values() rather than entrySet() makes the code more readable
```

The general lesson is that using lambdas requires a different mindset, one closer to functional programming (where the concept of lambdas originates), rather than trying to impose the same imperative principles on it. The correct way to get information out of lambdas is by evaluating them, not by a side effect.

Comment: "The correct way to get information out of lambdas is by evaluating them". So lambdas to return a value? I understand that filter() is basically taking a method as an argument, which is returning a Boolean value, but what mechanism actually returns that Boolean? Is it always implicit, as in the last statement of the lambda?

Comment: @BrianHVB No, it isn't always implicit, you can use an explicit `return` statement too, if you define your lambda like this: `v -> {return v==2;}`. But if your lambda is just a single expression (`v -> v == 2`), its value will be the return value of the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

To keep with your current implementation, you'd use `map` instead of `forEach`, to return a value, and then `reduce` to accumulate:

```
pairsFound = map.values().stream()
       .map(value -> value == 2 ? 1 : 0)
       .reduce(Integer::sum);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand:
 .stream() --> sends each value to .map() --> which uses the value as a key and either 0 or 1 as the value --> then compute the sum of all the values?  I don't understand the (Integer::sum) expression but I will look it up. This approach seems similar to C#'s LINQ which I have some familiarity with. Thank you.

Comment: `Integer::sum` is a reference to the Integer.sum method. It is a binary operator that adds 2 values. `reduce` uses it to compute the whole sum.

Comment: This is a better answer for the question asked -- in general, use `reduce` (or `collect`) to replace a loop that calculates a value.